# Mongoose - cant push the result of findById into array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, mongoose

I am trying to push the result of an findById to an existing array. My code looks like this:

var targetArray = [];
var groupId; //gets the ID from another function.

```
Group.findById((groupId), (error, group) => {
  targetArray.push(group.toObject());
  console.log(targetArray);
}
console.log(targetArray);
```

The first log returns the array with the group in it, the second log returns an empty array [].

I tried it with and without the ".toObject()", I even tried pushing a simple string into the array. Everything vanished after I left the function.

I don't know if this is a mongoose-specific question or general javascript, but usually if I push something into an array it doesn't vanish on it's own.

Can you guys (and girls ofc) maybe point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: This operation is asynchronous, so it takes some time to finish and by the time you're making your `console.log()` the array `targetArray` it stills empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually more how javascript deal with asynchronous code.

It is happening because you are passing to the `findById` a callback function which will run some time in the javascript call stack. This means that as soon as you call `findById` function passing those arguments, javascript run the bottom `console.log` which in that case the array it's still empty.

The function that you have passed as an argument will run as soon as `mongoose` receive and acknowledgment from the mongo driver with some error or some data.

The truth is that this is expected and if you really want to do something with the data returned from `mongoose` you should in fact do it on the callback function.

Comment: thank you, that helped me understanding why my code wasn't working. Fixed that with a workaround